# Integration by substitution, problem below

Tags: integration

[image]

So this is the problem and the solution.

I was trying to solve the problem, I am getting stuck at "$du$".

I did:
\begin{align*}
u &= \sqrt{x^2-1}\\
du &= (1/2)(x^2-1)^{-1/2}(2x)xdx\\
   &= (x^2-1)^{-1/2}xdx\\
du &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
du/x &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx
\end{align*}

but now I don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: Please try to format your question in latex with some effort at spelling and capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us follow your book; you need to compute $$I=\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx$$ Make the suggested change of variable $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ that is to say $x=\sqrt{u^2+1}$; so $dx=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$. Replacing all of the above leads to $$I=\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do this 
$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx=-\int\frac{d(1/x)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}=-\arcsin{\frac{1}{x}}+C$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}~=~\int\frac x{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}~dx~=~\frac12\int\frac{d\big(x^2-1\big)}{\Big[(x^2-1)+1\Big]\sqrt{x^2-1}}~=~\frac12\int\frac{dt}{(t+1)\sqrt t}$$

Now let $t=u^2$, and use partial fraction decomposition. $($Alternately, let $x=\cosh y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x & =\int \frac{1}{x^2} d\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right) \\
& =\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)^2+1} \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$